# Where are Gradle logs?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle build for an app in Android Studio generates the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
cannot generate view binders com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for android.view.View$InvalidateInfo not found
```

Could anyone offer a tip on where to find the logs?

Initially I thought this was such a rudimentary question that the simple answer would pop up at the top for a quick search, but I failed to find it.

Please note this question is **about the logs**, not for this specific error. This error message is used just as an example. In case you are curious, this specific error was caused by not using the latest version (23) for compileSdkVersion in the build.gradle.

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file, often such errors occur because of data inconsistencies in build.gradle

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I do not want to distract people with the Gradle file. The error is related to data binding, and I can eliminate the error by removing a data binding.  This question is a general question about the logs, not for the specific error.  I will update the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Gradle does not redirect its logs in a separate file in Android Studio.

Therefore if you want to view them in a file, you need to build gradle using a command in the terminal and redirect gradle input to a file.

```
gradlew build > myLogs.txt 2>&1
```

This command will redirect all standard output and error messages from gradle build to a file called myLogs.txt in the project folder.

```
gradlew build > myLogs.txt 2> logErrors.txt
```

This command will redirect all standard output from Gradle logs to the myLogs.txt and all error messages to logErrors.txt

Tested on Windows 10 and works perfectly.

[Here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) is more information about how to redirect standard output from commands to different files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I am running Android on Windows 10.  Did you mean running Gradle in Android Studio does not generate log files?

Comment: Yes. I am running it on Windows 10 as well and I cant seem to find a way to run the gradlew build script through the terminal using a tee-like command. So two options there - run the command with a tee-like command that is supported on Windows or navigate a hook via a Log4j as said in the link above.

Comment: Tommorow at work I will try to execute this command on Ubuntu and I`ll see if it works. I have read that this is the way you can store your logs outside of the standard output

Comment: Thank you. If you could confirm Android Studio does not generate logs normally, it should be the answer to my question.

Comment: I did a search and found that gradle does not provide a general loging option for an external file. This is sugested here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/logging-to-console-and-file/8635 and on some other forum posts too.

Comment: Hello again, I checked and it turns out that gradle outputs its logs only in the standard output in Android Studio. If you need to see them in a separate file, you should build your project with a command and redirect the output to a file. I`ll update my answer. Just tested it and it works fine on windows 10

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it. As my understanding of your comment, the Gradle Build tab of the Messages window shows the logs referred to by the message which is a part of that window.

Comment: It's crazy that Android Studio has stopped showing Gradle build errors and they keep releasing new versions that still have this critical bug.

Answer (score 48):

View -> Tool Windows -> Build.

There is small "ab" button on the left panel.

[image]

All gradle logs for current build are there.

[image]

**EDIT**: There is new icon from AndroidStudio 3.3

[image]

Comment: The icon has changed, but it is still there. Hint text on hover it "Toggle view".

Comment: Saved my life. The Kotlin compiler was showing a pile of stack traces which I didn't find useul

Comment: The button has gone away. Now you click on the top line ("Build: ...") to show the whole log.

Comment: This button is not visible in Dolphin version. Does anybody know how can I see logs?

Comment: As Erik says, instead of the button you click on the "Build projectname:" top item in the status or problem listing. The top line looks like just a header but actually it is how you bring up the gradle log.

Answer (score 28):

You can also try running your task like this:

> >gradlew --info build

You will get a bunch of useful log information

Comment: why downvote? Gradle itself prints `Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.` at the bottom of its output
_"Ah, the kids nowadays, they avoid the holy terminal"_

Comment: This is what I need, to see full expanded log in command line. This is useful and good answer! I am using Gradle 5.5.1

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Android Studio just reported "Read timeout" with nothing else.  Annoying.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio 4 (at least 4.2.1 now), both the `ab` button and the `Toggle View` button (mentioned in another answer) are gone, so Android Studio doesn't show the logs in the Build View anymore, but if a gradle sync fails, there is a button that brings you to view the idea log outside Android Studio (see the right-most button below), entitled "Show Log in Finder" (at least, in MacOS Android Studio).
[image: Show Log in Finder]

Answer (score 1):

Ashakirov's answer is almost the ultimate one. Just a little update, in newer Andy Studio release, e.g. Dolphin (2021.3.1 Patch 1), the "/ab" icon is gone. "Build Analyzer" is a new tab introduced in "Build" tool window, to take place of "/ab". Just select and run "Build"->"Rebuild Project" from the menu, and after the build finish, choose "Tasks" option from the top-left drop-box in "Build Analyzer" tab in "Build" winodw, and Andy Studio will show all the Gradle tasks been run in the build.

P.S. Ajaxian's answer is good for CLI in "Terminal" window though.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows version of Android Studio, there should be a "Show Log in Explorer" link that will reveal the Gradle log:

[image]