# Unable to run kotlin with dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm new to kotlin and dagger 2. I try to following this [guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2#instantiating-the-component) in Android Java. but error was throw...

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   Internal compiler error. See log for more details

What did I do wrong?

**Application**

```
class App : Application() {

    val netComponent: NetComponent by lazy {
        DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(this)) // This also corresponds to the name of your module: %component_name%Module
                .netModule(NetModule("https://api.github.com"))
                .build()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    fun netComponent() : NetComponent = netComponent
}
```

**NetComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules= arrayOf(AppModule::class, NetModule::class))
interface NetComponent {
    fun inject(activity: HomeActivity)
}
```

**NetModule**

```
@Module()
class NetModule(baseUrl: String) {

    val mBaseUrl: String = baseUrl;

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providedSharedPreferences(app: Application): SharedPreferences {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpCache(app: Application): Cache {
        val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MiB
        return Cache(app.cacheDir, cacheSize.toLong())
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providedGson(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(cache: Cache): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(gson: Gson, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }

}
```

**AppModule**

```
@Module()
class AppModule(val app: App) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApp() = app

}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(app: App)
}
```

**Finally, HomeActivity**

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        (application as App).netComponent.inject(this)
    }
}
```

> It's build failed when I start using @Inject annotation to
>   HomeActivity Class.

**Gradle App**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.viinsoft.mobile.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // App's dependencies, including test
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dragger"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dragger"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintLayout"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espressoVersion"

    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$mockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$hamcrestVersion"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$powerMockito"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$powerMockito"

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$runnerVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rulesVersion"

    // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })
    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })
    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

**Gradle Project**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.1'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.0.2'
    constraintLayout = '1.0.2'
    retrofit = '2.3.0'
    gson = '2.8.1'
    glideVersion = '4.0.0'
    guavaVersion = '23.0-android'
    dragger = '2.11'

    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    powerMockito = '1.7.1'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    runnerVersion = '1.0.0'
    rulesVersion = '1.0.0'

    // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
    espressoVersion = '3.0.1'
}
```

**EDIT GRADLE LOG**

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Internal compiler error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:9)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptTask.compile(KaptTask.kt:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: Post your gradle log.

Comment: where can I get this log @DmitriiNechepurenko where is the log keep

Comment: If you use android studio - right down corner "gradle console"

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558637/where-are-gradle-logs

Comment: @DmitriiNechepurenko nothing come out when run the command in terminal, only create log file.

Comment: Is log file empty? Try './gradlew build' in terminal

Comment: @DmitriiNechepurenko I edit question, added log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by update AppModule

> from App (which extend Application) to Application

**FROM**

```
@Module()
class AppModule(val app: App) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApp() = app

}
```

**TO**

```
@Module()
class AppModule(val app: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApp() = app

}
```

I don't know why, but maybe NetModule.class, some provided method required Application as input parameter, so Dragger may not know that App is extend from Application class, result in fail to resolved injection.

anyone can confirm on this assumption. please confirm.

Comment: You did not include the full error log. If you'd have scrolled up a bit further you'd have discovered something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367 In your case Dagger only knew about your implementation `App` but you were requesting an `Application`. You could also have solved this by adding `: Application` as the kotlin return type, or adding `@Binds fun bindApp(app: App) : Application` to your module

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dagger2 on Kotlin, try to do this:

```
@Inject lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

instead of:

```
@Inject var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
```

in this way I've solved also the problem of Butterknife.

**EDIT**: open Gradle Console, it could give the error:
[image]

Comment: still, Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

Comment: a question: why you use implementation instead of compile when you declare dependencies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153546/discussion-between-ste9206-and-jongz-puangput).

Answer (score 0):

Sometime before I faced the same problem and ruined my 1 day to find the solution for this. And as per my experience I am listing few points below which developer must take in consideration while integrating Dagger2 with android kotlin.

1. The scope used in `Component` & `Module` classes must be same.
2. `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt` must be in your `build.gradle` file, without this you are not able to generate `DaggerComponent` class.

Hope it will help some developers out.