# After installing Android Studio 3.1 I get "AAPT2 error: check logs for details"

Tags: android

I tried turning off AAPT2 but it didn't work. Below is the log.

> Build: build failed   5s 44ms Run build   4s 889ms Load build 47ms Run
>   init scripts  43ms Evaluate settings  2ms Configure build 776ms
>   Calculate task graph  2s 211ms Run tasks  1s 839ms null
>   /Users/dt/AndroidStudioProjects/HappyBirthday 
>   app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml  error: resource
>   dimen/activity_vertical_margin (aka
>   com.example.android.happybirthday:dimen/activity_vertical_margin) not
>   found.     error: resource dimen/activity_horizontal_margin (aka
>   com.example.android.happybirthday:dimen/activity_horizontal_margin)
>   not found.     null    failed linking file resources.

Comment: Can you post the contents of /Users/dt/AndroidStudioProjects/HappyBirthday app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml and also specify where dimen/activity_vertical_margin is defined? It looks like in activity_main.xml you are referencing a dimen that cannot be found.

Answer (score 6):

**After upgrading Android Studio you must invalidate caché and restart Android Studio**

`File` > `Invalidate Cache / Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer. It should be checked.

Answer (score 3):

It is due some error on xml file. If you using kotlin its very hard find xml errors and it result causes simply build failures and no proper error log generated. Try below commands in android studio terminal and it will give where the error occurs exactly.

```
> ./gradlew clean 
> ./gradlew assemble
```

Comment: Baffling as to why a modern IDE specifically designed for Android is incapable of displaying common errors. But after running these commands from the command line, I can clearly see my error: "activity_transfer.xml:7: AAPT: error: junk after document element." rather than the less than helpful “AAPT2 error: check logs for details” presented in the IDE.

Comment: [Where are Gradle logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558637/where-are-gradle-logs)

Comment: @Elletlat, Gradle logs are coming on android studio terminal, if run above commands

Comment: Yes I know. The other link I posted relates to people attempting to access the logs without running the commands.

Answer (score 0):

check your XML files for errors, there could be an error in

> dimen

it says that

> dimen/activity_vertical_margin

not found.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research and this is what I found. Sometimes the problem is in the XML files when you're referring to a resource that Android Studio doesn't know where to find. In my case I was trying to set the color of an item using `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` instead of `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"`.

Also, in some cases if you're trying to get the dimension of the action bar like so `android:height="?attr/actionBarSize"` it will result in the exception you mentioned. To get rid of it you should use    `android:height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`. So make sure to check all recently modified XML files for these types of mistakes.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it just by reinstalling Android Studio 3.1. Thanks for your suggestions.