# android.enableAapt2=FALSE error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, aapt

After updating my android studio to `gradle:3.1.2`(latest version) i get `android.enableAapt2 notification EVENTHOUGH` i set it `FALSE` before update!!

The NOTIFICATION is;

```
"The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning. It will be removed at the end of 2018.."
```

After this notification i set `android.enableAapt2` to `true` and i get the error below. Would you please help me..[This is what i see after changing Aapt2 from false to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf5If.png)

[assembleDebug output of my updated gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSIPa.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545038/after-installing-android-studio-3-1-i-get-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-details

Comment: You are getting the warning (notification) about the flag being disabled soon, because it *will* be. As for the error when AAPT2 is enabled, we need the build log to find it. Either add the build log from the Gradle Build window (full!) or go to your project's directory and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and post the output here. Without that we can't know what the error you're getting is.

Comment: i have edited my post regarding your feedback

Comment: I am getting kind of same errors after changing android.enableAapt2 to true. Any fixes?