# An easy way to print a variable in Android Studio's build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to print out a variable (example:${project.projectDir}) when I sync my Android Studio project with build.gradle, because I need to see the variable's value to make my task definition working properly.

I searched stack overflow and then followed others' suggestion, I tried follows:

```
project.logger.debug("@@@@@@@@@ ${project.projectDir}")
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@ ${project.projectDir}")
println "@@@@@@@@@ ${project.projectDir}"
```

But none of above working, the "Sync" pane at the bottom does not show anything.
Since Android studio does not provide "debugging gradle" function. 
So what **is the easy way to know a variable value defined/pre-defined in build.gradle**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create task inside project/module level build.gradle file, then add this code

   ```
   task sample { project.logger.lifecycle('my info message') }
   ```
2. to build `./gradlew sample`(Mac)
3. It will print inside android studio terminal.

**Output:**

[image: outpput]

Comment: The log solution requires manually building build.gradle outside Android Studio and redirect stdout into a text file. See [Where are Gradle logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558637/where-are-gradle-logs).

Comment: Thanks, I think so far this is the best solution.

Comment: If there is no other solutions better / easier than this, I'll accept it as the answer.