# Bug in compiler Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

I am using Android with databinding and it's been several times that I get build errors like in this gist below:

https://gist.github.com/MwBakker/2cfc1c4e6e73ed74452166fff83a0251

I can't print the error in this question due to all the whitespace, but that particular white space is the exact problem.

Instead of showing me the cause of the error I get a lot of white space and then the build result telling me there is an error present during building.

The way it creates all the white space instead of my actual error makes it look like there is some bug present.

I can revert back but never get the actual error. How do I determine the error instead of seeing all the white space in my build result?

Tried so far:

- building in release
- reverting back to the error (no actual cause found so far)
- building per terminal (result below)
- pipe the output of the build error to a file: `build command >> file.txt`, no result

### build in terminal

building in the terminal `gradlew build` did leave result instead of white space except the error gets cut off so the full message is yet not visible:

https://gist.github.com/MwBakker/84c932f47ded402b1eaf4762fbfd15d0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by performing a termninal build as followed:

```
gradlew build > myLogs.txt 2> logErrors.txt
```

`logErrors.txt` contained the full non cut-off log which contained the error I was searching for.

Coming from this answer: [how to write full build log to file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35559344/4895256)