# Where is Gradle's Script object Logger configured?

Tags: gradle, logging

NB answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558637/where-are-gradle-logs) choose not to try to configure the `Logger`, but redirect standard output.

In a build.gradle file you can use the available `Script` object to obtain a `Logger`, using `getLogger()` ... or as this is Groovy, just go `logger`.

So I went

`logger.info "user log message... where does it go?"`

I kind of expected this to printed out through `stdout` with the other Gradle messages... but no. Then I changed the level to `error` (or `lifecycle`), and it printed out OK to `stdout`.

Unfortunately from within the `Logger` class there isn't a way to find how it's configured. Is all this just hard-wired and not really meant to be tweaked by the user? It'd be quite nice to be able to log to a file as well as the CLI, change the log levels to include `info`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The logger prints to `stdout`. It depends how you invoke gradle.
Gradle knows multiple verbosity flags for its output.

```
-i, --info                Set log level to info
-d, --debug               Log in debug mode (includes normal stacktrace).
--warning-mode            Specifies which mode of warnings to generate. Values are 'all', 'summary'(default) or 'none'
```

So for logs pushed to `info` you need to invoke gradle with `-i`. If you want your messages visible all the time you need to use `lifecycle` as this is the default level visible.