# When running java-based code through the command line via Gradle, where do Logger messages go?

Tags: java, gradle, logging, command, println

So I've been running some java code through the command line using gradle for the first time, and can't get logger messages or system print messages to show up in the command line output. So where does this output end up? I need to debug some things, have been unfortunately forced to use command line, and need to see some logger/error messages.

Comment: That entirely depends on how you configured the logger, and how to configure logger depends entirely on which logging framework you use, so the short answer is: *It depends*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are Gradle logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558637/where-are-gradle-logs)