# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@d5789c4

Tags: parsing, error-handling

Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@d5789c4.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@57808e1e.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same message of error and it resulted to be this annoying litle mistake in the color resource file: the double angle bracket, which by the way the compliler doesn't highlights
>@color/gris_oscuro

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem in some resource file.  I think it's very frustrating, the error message says "Check logs for more details" but I am not sure how to get the logs.

I had a similar problem and after many attempts I exited Studio, manually removed the build directory, and tried again.  This time I did see a log, and they pointed at my `strings.xml` file, which I was able to fix.

By the way, I realized that if you run "Compile `some_file.xml`" from the Build menu, you'll get the error even if the error is somewhere else. So this is not helpful.

(FWIW, my error had to do with a single quote inside a `[[CDATA]]` block.  I thought that Xml allows any text inside `CDATA`, but maybe Studio is less forgiving.  Anyway, your error is probably something else, you'll just have to find it.)

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558637/where-are-gradle-logs) that people discuss how to get grade logs.  I was not able to run `gradlew` from the terminal (I am on macOS) but that seems to be the official way to get lgs.

Answer (score 0):

Check colors.xml and strings.xml file. I had error in colors.xml. I had written wrong color code of two colors. That is why I was getting this error.